# Box Java SDK - Download OutOfMemoryError when downloading 500MB file

Tags: java, box

java-sdk-2.8.1.jar from my Java program. In this program using the com.box.sdk.BoxFile download api I download the file from box and process it in my application. The code below works fine with smaller files however when downloading 500 MB file I get java.lang.OutOfMemory error at line file.download(outputStream). Please advise.

```
public void downloadFile(BoxAPIConnection boxConn,String boxFileID, ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream) throws Exception {
BoxFile file = new BoxFile(boxConn, boxFileID);
file.download(outputStream);
}
```

Comment: By the way, the tag description for [tag:box] includes "Avoid using this tag. It has multiple unrelated meanings and therefore could be confusing."

Comment: It would be better to process the file as you read it, rather than reading it into an array and then processing it. That way you can process files of arbitrary size. Whether that’s possible depends on what operations you’re performing.